# -webkit-scrollbar for X axis only

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I know that this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

can hide the scrollbar of an element, but it hides both the x and the y axis. I would like to hide only the x axis scrollbar and keep the y. Is there a standard way to do this? I'm looking for something like:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-x {
    display: none;
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit: `overflow-x: hidden` will not work.**

Comment: Can you use the standard `overflow-x`?

Comment: Unfortunately, in my scenario, I can't.

Comment: What's that scenario? Maybe you're using bootstrap?

Comment: My content overflows in the x direction, but I've disabled scrolling of x with overflow-x:hidden. But on mobile, when I scroll down, the x scrollbar is still shown as scrollable, even though the content isn't.

Comment: try set position:fixed or width:100%. If it doesn't work, could you share that part of the code?

Comment: Nvm, I used another way to fix it. Thanks for your support, I'll accept your answer to end this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The standard for displaying both scrollbars is:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

but, if you only want vertical scrolling you can use:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

for more details you could see:

[w3Schools - CSS overflow-y Property](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested use `overflow-x: hidden;` to hide the x-axis scroll bar. If you only include `overflow-x: hidden;` then this will only hide your x-axis scrollbar and not the y-axis one. If you want to hide both of them, then you would also have to include `overflow-y: hidden;`

Hope this explains.